# Symfony - Doctrine filter date if end date is null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have tricky one, I am trying for days to fix the issue.

I have **Reports** and **Subscriptions**.

I have specified one date for report.. (Report entity has *reportDate* filed)

Idea is to return one result for that specific report day.

Then in a query builder, I am triggering Subscriptions table that has *startDate* and *endDate* filed.
Idea is to find table row in Subscriptions that exists in a date range of reportDate.

So, I am filtering trough Subscriptions to find one that is valid on a given day.

In my form if I input **2020-11-01 to 2020-11-10** and it filters in my custom foreach array and return excepted results.

Problem: The endDate is optional and can have NULL value.
What I want to accomplish there is that if *endDate IS NULL* to filter all results from startDate to the future. Right now when I iterate trough all Subscriptions then result is always 0 value.

Method that handles it:

```
public function getSubscription($reportId, DateTime $reportDate)
{
    $from = new DateTime($reportDate->format("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00");
    $to   = new DateTime($reportDate->format("Y-m-d")." 23:59:59");

    return $this->createQueryBuilder("e")
        ->where('e.reportId =:reportId')
        ->andWhere('e.startDate <= :from')
        ->andWhere('e.endDate >= :to')
        ->setParameter('reportId', $reportId)
        ->setParameter('from', $from)
        ->setParameter('to', $to)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

also tried to add:

```
->andWhere('e.endDate >= :to AND (e.endDate IS NULL OR e.endDate >= :to)')
```

result was the same.

Comment: Have you tried just with `'e.endDate IS NULL OR e.endDate >= :to'`? Seems like that would be the logic you are describing.

Comment: Yes I am. No luck. :( @El_Vanja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  Your problem is this:  `e.endDate >= anything` is false whenever `e.endDate` is null.

Try this, simplifying the thing you mentioned in your question.

```
->andWhere('(e.endDate IS NULL OR e.endDate >= :to)')
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you :D @O.Jones

Comment: Is there any reason why the last day is never included. If 2020-11-01 to 2020-11-10, last result is 2020-11-09? @O.Jones

Comment: what are the data types of the columns `startDate` and `endDate`?

Comment: it was date so a changed to datetime, but nothing changed @O.Jones